# Single word for "from then" or "from it"

Tags: synonyms, word-usage, technical, archaicisms, construction

I would like to use the *archaic* expression (from the family of *hence, whereby etc.*) to refine the sentence:

"..the weights introduced in Exercise 2 and determined *from it/from there*"

meaning the weights were presented and their utility described with Exercise 2 during which their optimal values were selected.

My instinct would point towards  *whence* , used as in

".. in Exercise 2 and determined *whence*."

but I'm not too sure whether the meaning (Merriam Webster: from what place, source, or cause) can be bent to what I'm thinking or if the word can even be used this way at all (at the end of a sentence).

Any insights would be greatly appreciated,

thank you all.

Comment: How about thereby (adv): By that, from that.

Comment: “The weights […] determined from then/there” does not make any kind of sense to me to begin with. Are you simply trying to say, “The weights introduced and determined in Exercise 2”?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to use a word so archaic that you can't decide between whence/thence/etc.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet no I am not trying to say that, everybody knows that there is always a way to rephrase a sentence. But once the question has sprung it is better to answer it and learn something new than to simply circumvent it:)

Comment: My question here is then: _what are you trying to say?_ The example you give is not English. It makes no sense. We cannot tell you which word you should use in an example that we do not understand the meaning of. Weights are not usually ‘determined’ at all, and certainly not _from_ anything. It doesn’t matter which of the words mentioned so far you put in, the sentence still doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Suddenly I wish there were an Archaic English Language Learners.

Comment: The question should be reopened. Whether about physical weights, mathematical weights, or the relative importance of  things,  the question is clearly about an exposition of the way in which weights have been determined.  The sentence refers to the  introduction (definition) of the weights in a previous exercise 2 and to their consequent determination from that exercise.  Thence is appropriate. Dictionary.com has Thence = from that fact or reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of **"thence"** as your mystery word?  Or **thereby**

Comment: thereby! EXACTLY. "Thence" I would say is pretty much the same as whence although it would indeed sound better in this case given the "from there" rather than "from where" connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

> "..the weights introduced in Exercise 2 and determined thusly.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are thinking of, funnily enough, is [*therefrom*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefrom):

> from that or it